# How to valid duplicate element in a list in java spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to valid 1 form from backend in java spring boot. When the ListUser of the form is duplicated, it will send an error message and not reload the page.
I have a class request

```
public class StoreInformationRequest {
private Boolean isReceiveReport;
private List<String> ipAddress;
private List<Integer> listUser;

public StoreInformationRequest(Boolean isReceiveReport, List<String> ipAddress, List<Integer> listUser) {
    this.isReceiveReport = isReceiveReport;
    this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
    this.listUser = listUser;
}
```

}

and Controller :

```
public String updateStore(@PathVariable("storeCode") String storeCode, @Valid StoreInformationRequest storeInformationRequests, RedirectAttributes attributes)
```

Comment: what do you mean by duplicated here? Are you talking about the values in listUser?

Comment: Use java.util.HashSet

Comment: @ProgrammerBoy yes. It is Integer in listUser, in here it is userId.

Comment: Before submitting the form, In the front end itself you can restrict the duplicate elements. Validation will not work to validate the contents inside the list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Discarding the duplicates

If you simply want to discard the duplicates, use a [`Set<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) instead of a [`List<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html). From the [`Set<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) documentation:

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements.

To discard the duplicates, you can use:

```java
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4);
Set<Integer> unique = new HashSet<>(numbers);
```

You also could use:

```java
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4);
List<Integer> unique = numbers.stream()
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

### Finding the duplicates

If you have a list and want to extract the duplicates, you can use the following:

```java
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4);
List<Integer> duplicates = numbers.stream()
        .filter(n -> Collections.frequency(numbers, n) > 1)
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

### Using Hibernate Validator

If you are using [Hibernate Validator](https://hibernate.org/validator/), a Bean Validation implementation, you could use [`@UniqueElements`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/UniqueElements.html) to validate that every element in the collection is unique.

To use it, ensure your list is annotated with [`@UniqueElements`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/UniqueElements.html):

```java
@Data
public class LotteryBet {

    @UniqueElements
    private List<Integer> numbers;
}
```

Then ensure your controller is annotated with [`@Validated`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html) and the `lotteryBet` parameter is annotated with both [`@RequestBody`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) and [`@Valid`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/Valid.html):

```java
@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/lottery")
public class LotteryController {

    @PostMapping(path = "/bets", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> bet(@RequestBody @Valid LotteryBet lotteryBet) {
        ...
    }
}
```

A request such as the one shown below will return `400` along with some details about the error:

```
POST /lottery/bets HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "numbers": [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
}
```

Comment: yes, but i want to show elements is duplicate for user.

Answer (score 2):

If you want distinct values in `listUser` you should use `Set` and not `List`.

Comment: sorry, your mean is change list to set. private Set<Integer> listUser;

Comment: Yes, you should do that.

Comment: You will never have duplicate if you change listUser to Set.

Answer (score 0):

Do as *Spasoje Petronijević* says above, use `Set` instead of `List` for `listUser`. Moreover, you are missing another thing: `@RequestBody` annotation.
So change your controller with this:

```
public String updateStore(@PathVariable("storeCode") String storeCode, @Valid @RequestBody
 StoreInformationRequest storeInformationRequests, RedirectAttributes attributes)
{
     //your code...
}
```